# What is the name of the sub-matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology, definition

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $n\times n$. Let $I=\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some $k\leqslant n$.

How to call the sub-matrix of $\mathbf{A}$ that has its indices in $I$? (I guess sub-matrix induced by $I$?)

*Example.* 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
$I=\{2, 4\}$.

Hence, the sub-matrix is

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{22} & a_{24}\\
a_{42} & a_{44}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}